# Convert a Minecraft vanilla server 1.14.4 to a modded server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

Basically we want to put this furniture mod : https://mrcrayfish.com/mods?id=cfm 
on our 1.14.4 server.

We have a vanilla server and don't want to lose progress (Buildings, Items, world etc.) but also want this mod installed. Is it possible for us to convert it to a modded server? If so how would I do this?

Comment: If you afraid of losing progress, you can take a backup of the world file.

Comment: I don't know that mod, but there should be absolutely no conversion progress. Just keep the world like it is.

Comment: Wouldn't you run into ore and mod related contet generation issues by just keeping the world file? at the very least for the discovered chunks of the map?

Answer (score 0):

create the modded server and then transfer the world files across.
you will still have all of your buildings and items and will be able to install mods.